# Calling JSON properties from an array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to call a single JSON key in JavaScript but I keep getting an 'undefined' value returned

I used PHP to extract the information from a MySQL database, and using `json_encode ($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`, created an array of JSON objects in PHP.

PHP code:

```php
require 'credentials.php';

$result = "Select * From table1";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

$json_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $jsondata=json_encode($row, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  array_push($json_array, $jsondata);

};
```

Then I passed the array of JSON objects to a JavaScript tag:

```js
var data = <?php print_r(json_encode($json_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));?>;   
console.log(data[0].keyToGetValueOf);
```

Suggestion as to how to retrieve the key for only 1 of the objects in the array?

Comment: it would probably be useful to see what your php actually renders as the javascript object to see the actual structure of the object you are trying to access.

Comment: You're double encoding. You should just append each `$row` onto `$json_array` and `json_encode` once at the end. Associative arrays will be encoded to objects by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd get the keys natively

```
console.log(Object.keys(data[0]));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

**PHP:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $data[] = $row;
}
$jsondata = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**HTML/JS:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
  var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsondata; ?>');   
  console.log(data[0].keyToGetValueOf);
</script>
```

Comment: `$json_array` != `$jsondata`

Comment: if this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify keys for the rows. So you would only be able to use the integer index to access a specific row in the array.